# Mapping a custom domain to a Glassfish application

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I am trying to map a domain `myapp.com` to an application on `glassfish 4`, but i couldn't manage to do it.

I followed a [tutorial](http://pe-kay.blogspot.com.tr/2013/05/configuring-virtual-servers-in-glassfish.html) which creates a **virtual server** for domain name then mapping its `docroot` to `${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/applications/myapp`.

I did the exact same things on the tutorial but i ended up reaching my application on `myapp.com/myapp` instead of `myapp.com`.

`myapp.com` still shows the default glassfish welcome page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the web application itself also has a context which is named `myapp` automatically.

You have to change the context root to `/` to deploy it at the GlassFish root context.

You can do this while deploying, in the Glassfish Admin GUI you can choose the context-root on the `Deploy` page, just set it to `/`.

Or via `asadmin`:

```
asadmin deploy --contextroot "/" webapp.war
```

Another option is to set the context-root for you web application via the `glassfish-web.xml` (if you don't have this file just create a new XML file in your WEB-INF folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/</context-root>
  <jsp-config>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but now both myapp.com and the server ip both shows the same myapp. Is this default behaviour if there is only one app on the server?

Comment: Yes this is the default behaviour, because the IP maps to the domain.